# DC power supply 10V AC between terminals and mains earth

Tags: ac, switch-mode-power-supply, oscilloscope, earth

My DC power supply shows 10V AC between earth and one of the terminals. How can I fix this, and is it safe to probe circuits with an oscilloscope, that are powered by it? The PSU ground terminal is connected properly.

Comment: What kind of power supply it is? Make, model, link to web page or manual? If it has a floating output, then the output is not ground referenced, and high impedance output can easily drift 10V AC even with small stray capacitances.

Comment: How it shows? Bring more details.

Comment: `10V AC between earth and one of the terminals` ... what about the other terminals?

Comment: If you’re using a multimeter to measure the voltage, be aware the the input impedance  is very high and will measure stray voltages. Even putting your fingers on the probes causes a voltage to be displayed. Put a 1k (not critical) resistor between earth and the psu output. Now measure the voltage.

Comment: what voltage is there form your finger to mains earth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My DC power supply shows 10V AC between earth and one of the terminals.

Mine does too (seriously).

> How can I fix this

It's not a bug, it's a feature. Why do you think you should fix it?

The DC power supply is floating, i.e. not referenced to earth. That's good!

It's not connected to earth with a low impedance connection. But it doesn't mean it's totally isolated from earth: there are still parasitic capacitances between the supply output and earth-referenced mains voltages. Those parasitic capacitances have low enough reactance, compared to your multimeter's input impedance, that you measure some "significant" voltage. I.e. the multimeter's input impedance isn't low enough to shunt those voltages to "zero".

If you *want* it referenced to earth, you must actually connect e.g. the supply's negative terminal to the earth terminal. Usually lab power supplies have an earth terminal on the front panel, so all you need is a jumper.

> is it safe to probe circuits with an oscilloscope, that are powered by it

Yes.

Additionally, the scope will usually provide an earth reference for the supply, since - again, typically - the scope probe GND/shield is connected to the PE (protective earth) through the scope's internals. So when you clip the "ground" clip of a probe to your DC supply's negative terminal, you earth-reference the DC supply. It's then unnecessary (and often counterproductive) to provide parallel earth paths through additional jumpers - that causes ground loops.

**TL;DR: If *you* want earth-referenced output in a lab supply, *you* have to provide a galvanic connection between one of the output terminals and earth.** Sometimes supplies have built-in toggle switches or captive jumpers that can be used to provide this connection. Other times, you have to supply a banana patch cord yourself :)